# Memory Layout of Linux (malloc() used in C, but does not start with the expected address)

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, memory-address

I used this chunk of code:

```
    int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *p;                   // memory for pointer is on "stack"
    p = malloc(sizeof(int));  // malloc'd memory is on "heap"
    assert(p != NULL);
    printf("(pid:%d) addr of p:        %llx\n", (int) getpid(), 
       (unsigned long long) &p);
    printf("(pid:%d) addr stored in p: %llx\n", (int) getpid(), 
       (unsigned long long) p);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get:

```
addr of p:        7ffc0c53e3e0
addr stored in p: 558ae195c260
```

Now, first of all, since the program only does this, I do not understand why `malloc()` does not start with the address `00200000`? Second, can I say that the `7ffc0c53e3e0` address is in `heap`, and the address `558ae195c260` is in `stack`? Third, if my guess with `00200000` is wrong, is there any logic with the addresses that I get, or is it completely random?

When I think about it, the address is not even 32 bits, it is 48 bits. Even if it is to be more than 32 bits (I have 8 GB memory, so I believe it must be more than 32 anyways), why is it not expressed in 64 bits, since the processor is 64 bits.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think the address returned by `malloc()` should start anywhere in particular, such as 0x00200000?  There's nothing that says where the heap memory must be allocated, except that it won't be placed so it overlaps with any other allocated memory segment.  The 0x7FF… address is most likely a stack address, not a heap address, and the 0x558… address is a heap address, not a stack address (that's the reverse of what you thought).  The address is indeed a 64-bit address; the leading 4 zeros have simply been omitted as uninteresting.

Comment: Please include the program that produced those results in your question. Don't ask us to rely on what you think "addr of p" and "addr stored in p" mean.

Comment: @KeithThompson I did.

Comment: The correct way to print a pointer value is to cast it to `(void*)` (if it isn't already of that type) and use the `%p` format specifier. And your program is incomplete; it's missing at least 4 required `#include` directives. And the output you show in your question is not the output of that program. See [mcve].

Comment: The comments in your program seem to answer your question correctly.

Comment: **why** would you expect things? `malloc()` is expected to return a pointer or a NULL pointer. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux implements [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), so as far as I'm aware you always get random addresses. `558ae195c260` is actually allocated on the heap via `malloc()`, whereas `7ffc0c53e3e0` is allocated on the stack when you declare `int *p;`. 48 bits is still enough for 256 TB of RAM, but beyond that some architectures don't allow all address lines to be a full 64 bits (like AMD64).

Hope that helps. If anything I've said is wrong or misleading please correct me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

No, `p` is in stack (or global) and it points to a bunch of memory in the heap.

Regarding `malloc()` , if you are working on an OS, it depends on the kernel, and how it is managing the memory.

Finally, obviously some of your data is wrong. A 32bit bus data cannot manage 8GB of RAM (no more than 2^32=4GB). However, it makes sense in a 64bits bus, because a 64bits variable has enough space to contain an 8GB address.